# Make some changes of google streaming speech recognition and it does not work

Tags: c#, async-await, anonymous-function, google-speech-api

I'm working on the google streaming speech recognition.Now I'm trying to take the parameters out of the WriteAsync, but I can't figure out why I can't receive any text.
Here's the previous code:

```
 await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
      new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
      {
          StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
          {
              Config = new RecognitionConfig()
              {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                SampleRateHertz = 32000,
                LanguageCode = "en",
               },
                InterimResults = true,
            }
       });
```

Here's the code that I made some changes:

```
RecognitionConfig config = new RecognitionConfig();
config.Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16;
config.SampleRateHertz = 32000;
config.LanguageCode = "en";
await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
  new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
   {
      StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
       {
         InterimResults = true,
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are not using your RecognitionConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your `RecognitionConfig`:

```
RecognitionConfig config = new RecognitionConfig();
config.Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16;
config.SampleRateHertz = 32000;
config.LanguageCode = "en";
await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
    new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
    {
        StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
        {
            Config = config, // You are missing this line
            InterimResults = true,
        }
    });
```